# tab does not scroll while swiping the layout

Tags: android, tabs, swipe

This is my activity ,`tab` does not scroll while swiping the layout, here is my code :

```
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class ProgramInfoActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements  android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener {

private static final String TAG = "STRING";
private ViewPager viewPager;
private ProgramTabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
Intent intent;
Fragment fragment;
// Tab titles

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_program_info);

    intent = getIntent();


    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager1);
    mAdapter = new ProgramTabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
//  fragment = new Fragment();
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    //     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("UnderGraduate").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_academic).setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Graduate").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_ic_course).setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("PostGraduate").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_academic).setTabListener(this));
    /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    Log.v(TAG, "clicked");
    if (tab.getPosition()==0) {



    }

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

}

<< my fragment >>>

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
 //   programInfo = (TextView) vg.findViewById(programinfo);
    listView = (ListView) vg.findViewById(R.id.programinfo);
    layoutInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    dbFields = new DbFields();
    dbHelper = new DbHelper(this.getActivity());

    readJsonProgram();

    programAdapter = new ProgramAdapter(this,layoutInflater,programList);
    listView.setAdapter(programAdapter);
   }
```

Comment: use this for tab newer class https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html

Comment: my code works fine on other class but does not works in here

Answer (score 0):

You have to add code for onPageScrolled in setOnPageChangeListener Mehtod.

```
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
      //write your code here to scroll
    }
```